# MySql , Pagination

Tags: mysql, pagination

I have ten tables in mysql with same number of columns eg Id,Name,Timestamp . Each table contains around 1 million records. I have to show consolidated data from all tables to one place. What is the best way to get paginated data sorted by timestamp. eg If I have to show page number 4 and page size is 25 then I should get 76th to 100th records , sorted by timestamp as if they were in single table.

I have written it as(4th page ):

```
select * from (
               (
                Select * from TABLE1 limit 0,100
               )
               UNION (
                Select * from TABLE2 limit 0,100
               )
               UNION (
                Select * from TABLE3 limit 0,100
               )
               UNION (
                Select * from TABLE4 limit 0,100
               )
              ) t
limit 75,25
```

This works fine for small page sizes(upto 100) but is very slow for >20. How it can be improved? Is there another way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use ElasticSearch :-}

Comment: Just my opinion but you shouldn't waste time on optimizing pagination for more than 10 pages - aim for user friendly filtering instead. Show me one user that will wade through > 10 pages of 100 items/lines each.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're paginating over each table, instead of on the whole result.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table4
) t
ORDER BY t.timestamp_col
LIMIT first_rec, page_size;
```

The next thing to do is to be sure to have an index on those `timestamp_col`, but I'm not sure that a regular index for each table will work, so you'll have to run an `EXPLAIN PLAIN` on that query.